# Set Coldfusion Variable with javascript for use in replace() on same page?

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion, replace

I'm trying to set a coldfusion variable after form data entered on the same page is posted to a CFC via json to be stored in DB.

A modal pops up with the option to send a welcome email to the client. The content of that email is precomposed and stored in the DB. We pull it and we run rereplace() on the string a few times to insert things like the client specific login and password that was just set on the previous form.

So I'm trying to get the login and password variables set as coldfusion variables so they can be used in the rereplace() functions to add them to the email message string, so the client will receive their credentials.

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <cfparam name="ClientLogin" default="">
    <cfinput type="Text" id="ClientLogin" name="ClientLogin" value="#ClientLogin#" required="Yes" message="Client Login is required" maxlength="60" class="inputText430">
    </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>
    <cfparam name="ClientPassword" default="">
    <cfinput type="Text" name="ClientPassword" value="#ClientPassword#" required="Yes" message="Client Password is required" maxlength="15" class="inputText430">
    </td>
</tr>
```

ClientEmailNotes is puled from query, and I need the ClientLogin and ClientPassword coldfusion variables set from the form inputs.

Part of Modal:

```
<cfset ClientEmailNotesStr = #clientemailDefault.ClientEmailNotes#>

<cfset ClientEmailNotesStr = Replace(ClientEmailNotesStr,"CLIENT_LOGIN","#ClientLogin#","ALL")>
<cfset ClientEmailNotesStr = Replace(ClientEmailNotesStr,"CLIENT_PASSWORD","#ClientPassword#","ALL")>
<cfset ClientEmailNotesStr = Replace(ClientEmailNotesStr,"COMPANY_NAME","#companyname.Company#","ALL")>

<textarea name="Message" cols="90" class="textArea430" wrap="virtual" style="width:420px; height:93px;">
#ClientEmailNotesStr#
</textarea>
```

Please let me know if I need to elaborate.
I notice sometimes after looking at a problem, I've internalized the question so much that I may not describe it well enough.

Thank you in advance,

Steven

Comment: Sending plaintext password is a no no in this day and age... but if you must.  is there a reason you can't pull the details at the same time as the text that you're storing in the db, by passing a newly created userid through the querystring?

Comment: Javascript takes place on the client.  ColdFusion variables exist on the server.  The exact solution to this situation is hard to determine with the information given.  Look at how the user name and password is generated.  That will get you started.

Comment: @Jarede, as far as sending the password, it's our subscribers setting up an account for their new clients. We will build in a better method on a new version, but this is what I have to work with for now. I had the same thought tho. For your other point, I'm open to any other ideas. What do you mean?

Comment: It really does depend on your setup... theoretically you could have it so when they submit the user/pass it returns the database userid, your modal doesn't popup till thats returned, then you pass the userid to the modal, the modals logic pulls the info from the DB...

Comment: don't use cfinput.. you will hate your self later.  Adds way to much overhead just to add a form field.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to a) take the form field values from the form, and b) apply them to your message in your modal. Is the modal code already a part of the DOM? If that's the case, you would use JavaScript to pull the values of the fields and replace the textarea text, rather than using CF, because it is already part of the DOM (no server request at this point). This is fairly straightforward, though (as mentioned), still not very secure, unless your modal post code is through secure socket. (You wouldn't typically email plain text un/pw anyway, but that's another discussion).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

I knew that CF is processed on the server, and JS is client side, but there was some code on the file that was distracting me from that. So I needed to be reminded of it for it to click from a different perspective.
So thanks for that.

The CFC mentioned, has been problematic since another guy rushed through it. Every week a different issue ends up stemming from it.

As far as handling plain text passwords is concerned, you are absolutely right. This is an outdated piece of s#!@ software that I'm gearing up to re-write, so I have have to pick my battles on what to fix, and there are plenty of other issues that need to be pounded out while it's live until I begin rebuilding in cake.

What I did was use the component, to run the replace() on based on if there is email content saved and then appended it to the textarea back on the form page for the email message in the modal.

CFC page that returns data to be appended:

```
<cffunction name="getEmailMessage" access="remote" returnformat="json">
<cfargument name="ClientLogin" default="">
<cfargument name="ClientPassword" default="">

<cfquery name="companyname" datasource="#arguments.datasource#">
SELECT STUFF
</cfquery>
<cfquery name="clientemailDefault" datasource="#arguments.datasource#">
SELECT STUFF
</cfquery>
<cfif clientemailDefault.ClientEmailNotes eq ''>

<cfset content.message='Hard Coded Text'>

<cfelse>

<cfset ClientEmailNotesStr = #clientemailDefault.ClientEmailNotes#>
<cfset ClientEmailNotesStr = REReplace(ClientEmailNotesStr,"CLIENT_LOGIN","#arguments.ClientLogin#","ALL")>
<cfset ClientEmailNotesStr = REReplace(ClientEmailNotesStr,"CLIENT_PASSWORD","#arguments.ClientPassword#","ALL")>
<cfset ClientEmailNotesStr = REReplace(ClientEmailNotesStr,"COMPANY_NAME","#companyname.Company#","ALL")>


<cfset content.message = #ClientEmailNotesStr# >

</cfif>

<cfreturn content>
</cffunction>
```

Thanks for everyones input.